# Unstable behaviour of Pybluez on different devices - Python

Tags: python, server, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, pybluez

I have 3 devices -> 2*PC and 1 Raspberry Pi. 2 PCs are only for the sake of testing. 2PC = 2 Laptops with Windows 10.

On raspberry pi I have Bluetooth service(Py 2.7 but 3.5 should also work if print()):

```
import bluetooth

try:
    server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
    server_sock.bind(("",0))
    server_sock.listen(100)
    bluetooth.advertise_service( server_sock, "MyService",
    service_classes = [ bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
    profiles = [ bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ] )
    client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
    print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)
    client_sock.send('Hello')
    data = client_sock.recv(1024)
    print("received [%s]" % data)
    client_sock.close()
    server_sock.close()
except:
    client_sock.close()
    server_sock.close()
```

On Laptops I have client

```
import sys
from bluetooth import *

try:
    service_matches = find_service(name="MyService",
    uuid = SERIAL_PORT_CLASS )
    print(service_matches)
    if len(service_matches) == 0:
        print('Found nothing')
        sys.exit(0)

    for i in service_matches:
        print(i)
    first_match = service_matches[0]
    port = first_match["port"]
    name = first_match["name"]
    host = first_match["host"]
    print "connecting to ", host
    sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
    sock.connect((host, port))
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    sock.send("hello!!")

    print(data)
    sock.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sock.close()
```

Everything works just fine, however, with one laptop I can repeat the proces between listening and connecting forever. With other Laptot I am able to connect 2-3 times and then I am receiving this error:

```
in <module>
    uuid = SERIAL_PORT_CLASS )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 204, in find_service
    addresses = discover_devices (lookup_names = False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 15, in discover_devices
    devices = bt.discover_devices(duration=duration, flush_cache=flush_cache)
IOError: No more data is available.
```

That means the error happened inside the pybluez function find_service. Interesting is that this happens when it cannot find a device. On the other laptop where this error is never triggered(always connects) but there are no devices ends up always with:
     print('Found nothing')

When the error starts to happen after 2-3 succesful connections, I need to restart Raspberry pi to be able to connect again.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was with this? I am running into a similar issue.

Comment: Yes and No. I dont know what is the solution, but I know something is wrong with the notebook. Till today I cant properly work with bluetooth but also, which is similarly disturbing, I cant find devices on my local network with python socket.gethostbyname. I feel its connected. I dont know how to solve it, but I am sure its hardware specific(I searched a lot and found nothing). When I use any other device(PC or other raspbery pi's) it works properly.

Comment: In relation to the problem with not finding devices on local network by hostname, I noticed that bluetooth is somewhat using network hostname. That gives me hope, that bluetooth is innocent and this whole problem is only related with my notebook

Comment: if it helps you, I found out that connecting directly via bluetooth is more or less reliable. That means if you know the mac address and you connect directly, it usually works

Comment: I am noticing a lot of the same things. When I use the Bluetooth MAC Address things tend to work fine. Unfortunately my goal was to do a discovery to get the MAC Address, but on one machine it was failing.